# How do i retrieve a list of machine on a specific version of windows

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a list of PC's where the name is equal to LN-M* and then from the reults filter out the ones which have a ReleaseID (Version of Windows) of 1703

Powershell -

## this is a list of the variables i will be using

```
$ReleaseID = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseID).ReleaseID
$ComputerName = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName" -Name ComputerName).ComputerName
```

## This is to filter the machines by name

```
$Threshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-400)

$DesktopPC = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties Name | 
    where (         
            $_.name -Like "LN-M*" 
        )

$results = $DesktopPC | select name
```

## These are the results I hope to get

```
ForEach-Object {$results -eq 
$_.ReleaseID -eq 1703 

 $ComputerName.Name

 }
```

Comment: Have any of these machines been upgraded in-place since they joined the domain? Because if not you can just get this information from Active Directory directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic example code below will do what you're asking for machines that are online and accessible. You'll need to add error checking and validation logic.

```
$targetMachines = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

#Filter by name right in your AD query instead of getting all computer objects
$allMachines = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -like "LN-M*"'

$allMachines | foreach {
    $dnsHostname = $_.DNSHostName

    # The remote registry service will need to be running on the the target machine
    $registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey("LocalMachine",$dnsHostname)
    $key = $registry.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
    $releaseID = $key.GetValue("ReleaseID")

    if ($releaseID -eq 1703)
    {
        $targetMachines.Add($dnsHostname) | Out-Null
    }
}

# These are the machines you are looking for (with Jedi hand wave)
$targetMachines
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark it as the answer if indeed it did.